# Vue component returning multiple table rows

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm attempting to return two tr elements from a single component `v-design-row`. I know vue requires the template elements to be wrapped in a div, but I cannot wrap them in a div because of the tag structure html tables require. When I add the second `tr` in the `v-design-row` component then vue doesn't render anything.

Can anyone suggest the best method for accomplishing this?

main.vue

```
   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody v-for="catagory in catagories">
            <v-catagory-row :catagory="catagory"></v-catagory-row>
            <v-design-row v-for="design in catagory.designs" :design="design"></v-design-row>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

v-design-row.vue

```
<template>
<tr>
    <td><img :src="design.image_directory" :alt="design.name"></td>
    <td>{{ design.name }}</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" :data-target="'#' + design.identifier" aria-expanded="false" :aria-controls="design.identifier">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Show
        </button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="switch">
            <input :id="'active'+design.id" v-model="design.active" class="btn-toggle btn-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
            <label :for="'active'+design.id"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        {{ design.sort_order }}
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="p-0" colspan="7">
        <div class="collapse" :id="design.identifier">
            <div class="p-3">
                {{ design.description }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since second `tr` in your `v-design-row` contains description of design, I'd suggest that this is whole element and it should occupy one row and have its own layout.

Alternatively, you can have a description separately and all other data in component.

Also, statement

> vue requires the template elements to be wrapped in a div

is not quite correct. Template can have any root element while it is a single element. So you can have

```
<template>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</template>
```

or even

```
<template>
  <tr v-if="condition == 1">
  </tr>
  <tr v-else-if="condition == 2">
  </tr>
  <tr v-else>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: I think I see what you getting at, I added the `v-for` to a template inside the `tbody`. This template can be used as a invisible html tag with vue logic.

Comment: You cannot use <template> inside a component template.

Comment: @marlar , [you can](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt).

Comment: @SuiDream. You are right, I was unclear. What I mean is that you cannot use <template> as a root element so the <template> doesn't solve OP's problem. For example, this is not allowed:<template>
  <template>
    <tr><td>{{ msg }}</td></tr>
    <tr><td>{{ msg }}</td></tr>
  </template>
</template>

Answer (score 3):

You are allowed to group row using multiple `<tbody>` sections like this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> ... </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr> ... </tr>
     <tr> ... </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
     <tr> ... </tr>
     <tr> ... </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use this in templates by using a `<tbody>` as the root element:

```
<template>
  <tbody>
    <tr> ... </tr>
    <tr> ... </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vue-fragment library. It allows you to have wrapper that wont actually be rendered.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31871177)