# How to return multiple rows from a Vue Component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In a nutshell I'm trying to do something like this in VueJS (v2.5.17):

```
<table>
  <my-multi-row-entry v-for="t in things" :thing="t" :key="t.id"/>
</table>
```

The catch is that each thing is represented by two `<TR>...</TR>` entries.  (I'm porting someone else's code; the table data in the first row spans to the second, etc., so *for now* I'd like to keep what they have.)

The obvious solution doesn't work, because VueJS needs to emit only one root element into the DOM.

**MyMultiRowEntry.vue**  *(not valid code, but shown for illustration)*

```
<template>
  <tr><td rowspan="2">{{ thing.foo }}</td><td>...</td><td>{{ thing.bar }}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>{{ thing.xyzzy }}</td></tr>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      thing: {
         type: Object,
         required: true
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Paths I've explored already:

- Vue does not have fragments (that I'm aware of), like `<React.Fragment>`, so I can't make a logical wrapper.
- HTML itself does not like a `<div>` wrapping table roles.
- The actual template content is more complex than this simple example, so it's not static content ...there's other Vue binding and such going on, which prohibits other trickery.
- The only other [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893445/vue-component-returning-multiple-table-rows) was taking a different approach and bumped into other problems.

**What's the best way to accomplish the above's intent?**

Comment: The proper element to group rows is `<tbody>`. In fact, it is **required**. As in, if you don't provide one, the browser automatically adds one for you. But it's really meant as a grouping mechanism for `<tr>`s and the implementation goes to reasons such as pagination when printing tables and so on. So that's what you should use, since a vue element requires the template to have a single child (at render).

Comment: Do note that you can't have both `<tr>`s and `<tbody>` elements as immediate children of the same `<table>`. `<tr>`s are valid `<table>` children ***only*** if no `<tbody>` is present (because, as I pointed above, all `<tr>`s are wrapped into one `<tbody>` automatically. But if you have one or more `<tbody>`s, `<tr>`s are no longer valid children of `<table>`. [Docs here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu -- _thank you_ -- that solved the problem _and_ explained what was going on. Elegant solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular example what I would do is just simply wrap multiple tr's into tbody container, as follow:

**MyMultiRowEntry.vue**

```
<template>
  <tbody>
      <tr><td rowspan="2">{{ thing.foo }}</td><td>...</td><td>{{ thing.bar }}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>{{ thing.xyzzy }}</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

Comment: Worked _perfectly_!  Thank you!!